# Is there a way i can join two tables and get the sum of duplicated field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model WarehouseTrade Account and WarehouseStorage Account
it look like this:-------

```
class WarehouseStorageAccount(models.Model):
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ITEM_GRADE_CHOICES)
    bags = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    gross_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=0)
    net_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class WarehouseTradeAccount(models.Model):
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ITEM_GRADE_CHOICES)
    bags = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    gross_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=0)
    net_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

### I am trying to get All the data in both accounts, but it should sum it up if there is a duplicate between the two.
I have been able to achieve this with SQL using below code:

```
SELECT 
    data.warehouse_id AS Warehouse, 
    data.item_id  AS Item,
    data.grade  AS Grade,
    SUM((data.net_weight)) AS Net_WEIGHT,
    SUM((data.gross_weight)) AS Gross_WEIGHT,
    SUM((data.bags)) AS Bags 
FROM 
    (SELECT warehouse_id, item_id, net_weight, grade, gross_weight, bags FROM public.inventory_warehousestorageaccount
    UNION ALL
    SELECT warehouse_id, item_id, net_weight, grade, gross_weight, bags
   FROM public.inventory_warehousetradeaccount
    ) data
    
GROUP BY data.warehouse_id, data.item_id, data.grade
```

I tried using union to join the two tables, then get the aggregate the result, but I keep getting an error

```
wt = WarehouseTradeAccount.objects.all()
ws = WarehouseStorageAccount.objects.all()
w=wt.union(ws)
w.aggreate(new_net_weight=Sum('net_weight')
```

How do I replicate this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't understand what do you mean by

> it should sum it up if there is a duplicate between the two

Do you want to remove the duplicates?

```
attributes = ('warehouse','item','grade'....)
result = []

wt = WarehouseTradeAccount.objects.all()
ws = WarehouseStorageAccount.objects.all()

for wtobj, wsobj in zip(wt,ws):
    for attribute in attributes:
        if getattr(wtobj, attribute) != getattr(wsobj, attribute):
            result.append(wtobj, wsobj)
            break
    else:
        result.append(wtobj)
```